# Comparison error for isometric sorting

Tags: java, sorting, libgdx, comparable, isometric

So I'm implementing an isometric sorter for my sprites and I'm having some issues with the comparison of when the tiles should be rendered. I'm sorting all the isometric sprites that will be rendered by implementing them as comparable.

The problem is, when I'm implementing the following compareTo method:

```
// 1 = render this after
// 0 == render same
// -1 = render this before
@Override
public int compareTo(IsoSprite o) {
    if(z >= o.z && maxY <= o.minY && maxX <= o.minX){
        return 1;
    }
    if(z >= o.z && maxY >= o.minY && maxX >= o.minX){
        return -1;
    }
    if(z > o.z){
        return 1;
    }
    if(z < o.z){
        return -1;
    }

    //z == o.z && maxY == o.maxY && minY == o.minY && minX == o.minX && maxX == o.maxX
    return 0;
}
```

I get the error "Comparison method violates its general contract!" from the array.sort call in the LibGDX Array (which I use for sorting). I can't tell how I am supposed to solve this when looking at other peoples issue with this error, but those problems are mostly trivial. Anyone know how I should solve this in my isometric comparison?

My isometric world (for reference):
[image]

Edit:
Found something interesting when only sorting by Z:

```
//Doesn't work
public int compareTo(IsoSprite o) {

    if(maxZ > o.z){
        return 1;
    }
    if (maxZ < o.z){
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

//Works
@Override
public int compareTo(IsoSprite o) {
    if(z > o.z){
        return 1;
    }
    if(z < o.z){
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But the problem is that I need to get the boundaries too with those individual if statements, I'll try to edit it so it'll be clearer

Comment: Hmm, I must be misunderstanding your problem, then.

Comment: How should the isometric sort behave if `maxX > o.maxX` but `minX < o.minX`

Comment: @MaxZoom not the same approach

Comment: Is your question more about how your comparison method is violating the contract defined by the `Comparable` interface, or is it a more general "how should I create a natural ordering of isometric elements" question?

Comment: maxX > o.maxX but minX < o.minX, would result in 1 if all z and y is assumed to be equal, but it all depends on the y and z as well of course

Comment: @azurefrog How the isometric comparison could be carried out without violating the contract. I know how the isometric ordering works, and I can create it while attached to a grid, I just can't grip a comparison of this many boundaries (needed for objects that aren't attached to a grid)

Comment: I believe the problem is that you have to compare the same values `minY < o.minY`, and not use `<=` and `>=` operators. Also if any number is a `float` or `double` then use their difference.

Comment: Yes that seems to be the problem, I guess i'll create a helper method that compares different variables to each other so I can compare min and max values

Answer (score 0):

This message indicates that there is something wrong 
with transitive logic in comparator, for if `A > B` then also `B < A` must be true. The compiler is smart enough to point it out to the user.
The problem in code is that a different values are compared to each other. To correct it you have to compare the same values `minY < o.minY`, and not to use `<=` and `>=` operators.

This should work:

```
public int compareTo(IsoSprite o) {
  if (isoDepth > o.isoDepth) return 1;
  if (isoDepth < o.isoDepth) return -1;
  return 0;
}
```

See [algorithm](https://mazebert.com/2013/04/18/isometric-depth-sorting/) to calculate isoDepth that could be used to sort /compare IsoSprites.

Comment: Yes, well when adding Math.signum infront and casting to int. The problem seems to be comparing different variables (see my latest edit)

Comment: Bad idea. What if `z == -2` and `o.z == Integer.MAX_VALUE` ? Then you get an integer overflow and not the correct result. Use `Integer.compare(z, o.z)` if you just want to compare two integer values.

Answer (score 0):

I realised I won't be able to do the comparisons needed in a comparable. So instead I'm using my own implementation of Quicksort to sort using my own compareTo method that basically checks if a sprite is behind or infront of another one.

Thanks for all the help anyway!